# How to add html css and javascript files to node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a folder with html files, a css file, and a javascript file along with images that I want to display in node.js. Is it possible to use all of that code already written and display that in a node.js app or would I have to recreate everything in node.js specifically? I've displayed the first html page, but the css and javascript I used does not work.

Comment: "display in nodejs" i guess you are new to node.js i would recommend to google for "express.js" and "ejs template engine" so set up an express server with ejs template

Comment: have a look at this: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to use a framework like [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to serve your static files.

Here's how you would do something like this in express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serves files in the public folder to the / route
app.use('/', express.static('public'));

// Use port 3000 for the server
app.listen(3000);
```

If your interested in doing it without Express (which I would not recommend) here is a [example](https://gist.github.com/mitrakmt/8227f72e4a6ff1381d9b37a966088087) I found and a [article](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/) as well.